# problems accessing project properties in visual studios 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

In VS2010 I am trying to access the properties of  my project.  when I try to do this I get the error below.

> An error occurred trying to load the project properties window.  Close
>   the window and try again. Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80004005 (E_FAIL))

I have tried removing all the references to this project but still get this error.  Any suggestions on fixing this problem?

Comment: I know this is basic, but have you tried restarting Visual Studio?  I will get errors like this after having VS open for a long time.

Comment: It smells like something went corrupted. Have you tried with another project?

Comment: I have restarted Visual Studio but to no avail.  I have tried accessing the properties of another project in the solution and I did not have any problems.  Just having problems with the one.